how to write an output in terraform module to get the bigquery table ids as part of data source?
I am trying to get list of tables in a bigquery dataset using terraform data source inside a module. I have written below code but it returns the entire path to the tables. I only need the table id.
data "google_bigquery_dataset" "dataset" { 
    dataset_id = "my-dataset"
    project    = "my-project"
}

output "bq_tables" {
    value = data.google_bigquery_dataset.dataset.access
}

I have checked the Google API documentation. The path it shows to the table list is given in this libnk. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets#DatasetReference
What I fail to understand is the syntax to use if possible after the access object.
e.g. I have tried be
low but it gives error Can't access attributes on a set of objects. Did you mean to access an attribute across all elements of the set?
value = data.google_bigquery_dataset.dataset.access[0].view.tableId[0]
value = data.google_bigquery_dataset.dataset.access.view.tableId[0]
